# cyclic vectors - cyclic subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on ${\mathbb R}^3$, which is represented by standard ordered basis, as follows: 
$$T(e_1) = 2 e_1,$$

$$T(e_2) = 2 e_2,$$

$$T( e_3) = -e_3.$$

I have to prove that $T$ has no cyclic vector. Also, to find what is the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by the $(1, -1, 3 )$ ?

Please suggest !

Comment: If a matrix is brought into diagonal (or triangular) form, it's cyclic vectors are easy to detect: it is necessary and sufficient that for each distinct eigenvalue the projection of the vector on the generalised eigenspace be a cyclic vector for the subspace, where projecting in this case means extracting the appropriate coordinates. Your example is quite easy in that the matrix is already diagonal. Only multiple eigenvalues need attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimal polynomial for $T$ is $(x-2)(x+1)$, but characteristic polynomial is $(x-2)^2(x+1)$, so they are not the same. Hence $T$ doesn't have cyclic vector by the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $T$ be a linear operator on $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. There exists a cyclic vector for $T$ if and only if minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial are the same.

**Proof:** Suppose there exists a cyclic vector $v$ for $T$, that is, we have $v\in V$ such that $\{v, Tv,...,T^{n-1}v\}$ span $V$. Then matrix representation of $T$ will be some [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), whose minimal and characteristic polynomial are the same.

Now conversely, if minimal and characteristic polynomial are the same, then we have a minimal polynomial which is of degree $n$. Take $v\neq 0 $, let minimal polynomial $p(x)= a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$. Degree of $p(x)$ is equal to the cyclic subspace generate by $p_v(x)$. Consider $\{v, Tv, T^2v,...,T^{n-1}v\}$, where $T$ is annihilator linear operator for $p_v(x)$ (following Hoffman-Kunze). This is a cyclic base. Read section 7.1 in Linear Algebra by Hoffman-Kunze.

Also we have $T(x,y,z)= (2x,2y,-z)$ Hence $T(1,-1,3)= (2,-2,-3)$ and $T^2(1,-1,3)= (4,-4,3)$.  We have (4,-4,3) is linear combination of $(1,-1,3)$ and $(2,-2,3)$. Hence the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $(1,−1,3)$ = linear span of $\{(1,-1,3), (2,-2,-3)\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @zapkm $+1$, could u tell me which book did u get this theorem?